# connect not change the props of child component when the prop object modified

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Hi I hava a component Sample wrapped with connect like

```
@connect(state => ({
    ....
    ....
}), {})
export default class Sample extends Component {
....
....
}
```

I import Sample from another componet and pass a prop name `data` as

```
....
data = {
a: 1,
b: 2
}

....
<Sample data={data} />
```

then my component renders with this data.

then I add new key value to `data` as

```
data = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c:3
    }
```

then my wrapped component never gets the updated prop. only `Connect` component gets the updated props.

then I modified the code by spreading data to a new object and pass to the child component. then it works perfectly.

```
<Sample data={{ ...data }} />
```

what is wrong with first method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to with `connect`. I believe the issue here is the mutation you're doing to the object `data`.

In JavaScript, we know this simple truth

```js
y = { a: 1 }
x = y;
console.log(x === y); // true
x.b = 2;    
console.log(x === y); // true
```

To trigger a re-render, React wants you to supply a new object, which you can achieve by one of the following.

```js
newData = { ...data, c: 3 };
```

OR

```js
newData = Object.assign({}, data, { c : 2 });
```

This is essentially the same happens when you do

```js
<Sample data={{ ...data }} />
```

It creates a new object on every re-render (even when you don't want it, hence not advisable).